# Trailing slash issue with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using these .htaccess commands to add a trailing slash at the end of my URLs.

```
# Redirect To Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder Or A File...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Its working great, however it breaks my laravel email verification because this URL

```
http://website.test/email/verify/12585/d3942dce589a8baf879be01b717184712b119a72?expires=1630646035&signature=59832e4888913f960ceec9c96e01d15bec742446bce834c37d4e0e8d67241c26
```

Becomes this URL (It adds a trailing slash at the end of the URL)

```
http://website.test/email/verify/12585/d3942dce589a8baf879be01b717184712b119a72/?expires=1630646035&signature=59832e4888913f960ceec9c96e01d15bec742446bce834c37d4e0e8d67241c26
```

How to add an exception for this particular URL?

Full .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect To Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder Or A File...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
    RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    # RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an exception in your rule:

```sh
# Redirect To Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder Or A File...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/email/verify/ [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]

# remove trailing / for /email/verify/...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/email/verify/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely.

Comment: Please show your full htaccess in question

Comment: I've updated the thread with my full .htaccess